# How to get objects with min values by category

Tags: javascript

I believe I have an array of javascript objects as follows, and I am trying to filter out all but the lowest prices for each item:

Have:

```js
const fruits = [
    {id: 1, fruit: "apple", store: "store1", price: 1},
    {id: 2, fruit: "apple", store: "store2", price: 1.25},
    {id: 3, fruit: "banana", store: "store1", price: 0.5},
    {id: 4, fruit: "banana", store: "store2", price: 0.75},
    {id: 5, fruit: "banana", store: "store3", price: 0.75}
];
```

Want:

```js
[
    {id: 1, fruit: "apple", store: "store1", price: 1},
    {id: 3, fruit: "banana", store: "store1", price: 0.5}
];
```

I imagine in SQL this would be accomplished with a group by statement such as "select fruit, min(price) from table group by fruit", but am not sure how I might accomplish this in its current object form.

I am looking for a JavaScript solution but am open to changing the data structure or using a framework if needed. I am already using React.js if that is relevant. Any guidance?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Seems like an object keyed by `fruit.fruit` would be sufficient: iterate over `fruits`, see if there's an entry for the fruit, if there isn't, just add one, if there is, compare the price and if it's lower, replace the `fruit`. Mind there are all sorts of fancy ways this could be done--it's almost always easier to start non-fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

object assign and reduce:

```js
const fruits = 
      [ { id: 1, fruit: "apple",  store: "store1", price: 1    } 
      , { id: 2, fruit: "apple",  store: "store2", price: 1.25 } 
      , { id: 3, fruit: "banana", store: "store1", price: 0.5  } 
      , { id: 4, fruit: "banana", store: "store2", price: 0.75 }  
      , { id: 5, fruit: "banana", store: "store3", price: 0.75 } 
      ] 


const mini = fruits.reduce((a,c)=>
              {
              let x = a.find(e=>e.fruit===c.fruit)
              if (!x) a.push(Object.assign({},c))
              else if (x.price > c.price) Object.assign(x,c)
              return a  
              },[])


console.log(  mini  )
```

> – Dave Newton : . With a map/object-based solution you iterate fruits once and let the result object handle lookups.

there is an other way for this :

```js
const fruits = 
      [ { id: 1, fruit: "apple",  store: "store1", price: 1    } 
      , { id: 2, fruit: "apple",  store: "store2", price: 1.25 } 
      , { id: 3, fruit: "banana", store: "store1", price: 0.5  } 
      , { id: 4, fruit: "banana", store: "store2", price: 0.75 }  
      , { id: 5, fruit: "banana", store: "store3", price: 0.75 } 
      ] 


const mini = fruits.reduce((a,c,i,t)=>
              {
              if (!a.find(e=>e.fruit===c.fruit))
                a.push(t.filter(e=>e.fruit===c.fruit).reduce((r,n)=>r.price<n.price?r:n) ) 
              return a  
              },[])

console.log( mini )
```

Comment: Should work, but wouldn't this have to keep pulling out the matching fruits, e.g., no longer O(n)?

Comment: `let x = a.find(e=>e.fruit===c.fruit)` will iterate the result array every time. With a map/object-based solution you iterate `fruits` once and let the result object handle lookups.

Comment: @DaveNewton  is my second solution suits better for you ?

Comment: Now for each fruit it runs find, filter, and reduce, so it's even worse.

Comment: @DaveNewton   No, you are wrong. Now he only searches for the lowest price once for each fruit. be just 2 times here, since there are only 2 different fruits

Comment: @DaveNewton, Now, for each element he searches [**in his answer**], and does [**only once**] a filtering and a reduction [**on each different fruit**]

Comment: So a find, filter, and reduce (nested in the enclosing reduce).

Comment: @DaveNewton not at all, you misunderstood my algorithm

Comment: The point is that this problem requires a single iteration through the source data. I don't understand why additional work is required, and you haven't explained why.

Comment: You do an outer reduce. Inside that you do a find, a filter, and another reduce. Do a simple time comparison with a large list.

Comment: @DaveNewton none of the solutions offered here does a single iteration on the source data, and all run sub iterations to determine the lowest price

Comment: I'm not sure I follow--Phil's answer does a single iteration on the source data. My original comment on the OP does a single iteration on the source data (equivalent to Phil's). There's no reason to iterate the source data more than once.

Comment: @DaveNewton Phil's answer make a double search itteration in hi line `if (!map.has(entry.fruit) || map.get(entry.fruit).price`,  `map.has(entry.fruit` search if they key in his map, and `map.get(entry.fruit).price` searh again this element to return a value

Comment: That is not an iteration. Map/object key lookup is O(1). This is all easily demonstrable--make a list of 100k random items and compare the three approaches (Phil's or mine and either of yours).

Comment: @DaveNewton whether in an object or in an array, finding the address of an element is always (in assembler) an iterative search. my solution is the same and requires less system resources

Comment: It isn't (or doesn't have to be, at least), but that's beside the point. That said--I ran the tests and you're absolutely right; your first answer *is* faster than the canonical solution--since the number of fruit names is relatively small that iteration is faster than the lookup. Mea culpa! That's awesome.

Comment: For reference, I created a jsperf page https://jsperf.com/lowest-price-operations/1 that shows the naive implementation, Phil's answer, and the two answers contained here. I didn't spend a huge amount of time checking the outputs or making sure everything was correct, but AFAICT it's roughly right.

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks for the benchmark speed test, I ended up thinking I can keep something positive from my years of assembly coding. The overabundance of object methods is not synonymous with efficiency. Do you owe me an upvote?

Comment: Nobody on SO owes anybody anything ;) But sure--although the additional complexity is likely over the head of the OP since the naive solution wasn't obvious to them :p

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via a [*reduce*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation, creating a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of *category* (`fruit`) to lowest price records.

For example

```js
const fruits = [
  {id: 1, fruit: "apple", store: "store1", price: 1},
  {id: 2, fruit: "apple", store: "store2", price: 1.25},
  {id: 3, fruit: "banana", store: "store1", price: 0.5},
  {id: 4, fruit: "banana", store: "store2", price: 0.75},
  {id: 5, fruit: "banana", store: "store3", price: 0.75}
]

const result = [...fruits.reduce((map, entry) => {
  // check for an existing record and if it has a greater price
  if (!map.has(entry.fruit) || map.get(entry.fruit).price > entry.price) {
    // set the new record for this category
    map.set(entry.fruit, entry)
  }
  return map
}, new Map()).values()] // now just get the values

console.info(result)
```

If there are multiple entries with the same price, this will keep the first one found. If you want to keep the last, use a `>=` comparison instead.

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is a good commonly needed operation to have handy.  I'd use that first to group the objects by fruit.  The second reduce (`minInArray`) also is a commonly used form to find min or max in an array.  Together they produce the min for each fruit type...

```js
const groupBy = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce(function(r, a) {
    r[a[key]] = r[a[key]] || []
    r[a[key]].push(a)
    return r
  }, {})
}

const minInArray = (array, key) => {
  return array.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    return prev[key] < curr[key] ? prev : curr
  })
}

const fruits = [{
  id: 1,
  fruit: "apple",
  store: "store1",
  price: 1
}, {
  id: 2,
  fruit: "apple",
  store: "store2",
  price: 1.25
}, {
  id: 3,
  fruit: "banana",
  store: "store1",
  price: 0.5
}, {
  id: 4,
  fruit: "banana",
  store: "store2",
  price: 0.75
}, {
  id: 5,
  fruit: "banana",
  store: "store3",
  price: 0.75
}];




let groups = groupBy(fruits, 'fruit')
let minPrices = Object.keys(groups).map(fruit => {
  return minInArray(groups[fruit], 'price')
})

console.log(minPrices)
```

Comment: I'm curious why to bother grouping them first; seems like it just adds another step to what's a single iteration over the array and dumping it back out to an array. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @DaveNewton - it's less efficient, but performed with generic operations that are frequently needed: grouping by a key, and finding the min/max by key.  The cost in compute resources on a small input is negligible.

Comment: Agreed the cost is negligible on small input--but (IMO) it implies there's a good reason to group it first, which there isn't in this case. Not saying it's not a nice thing to be able to do, but it adds complexity to a problem already a bit over the head of the OP.

Comment: @DaveNewton - if you're right about my idea adding complexity then that's a bummer, because that was the opposite of my intent. I was going for *simplification*, figuring that grouping then min-ing are a natural decomposition of the problem (with a side benefit of both being common toolbox tools). I realize this is subjective, but I just re-read the other answers, and mine is the only one that doesn't make *my head* spin :-)

Comment: It adds complexity by definition since it's performing an unnecessary operation, and genericizing the methods, while definitely useful, adds another layer. I don't understand how Phil's answer "makes your head spin" since it's identical but with better naming conventions ;)